# Does the default local content show when you toggle another locale/s off?

Tags: templating, localization, control-panel

With multiple locales setup when you toggle a specific locale off in the control panel for that entry, does the entry not show or will the output show the default locale content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you toggle off a locale for an entry, that entry will not show in that locale. So, if you have a section `news`, toggle off the entry `my-entry` in your current locale, and use `craft.entries.section('news')` to get all entries, `my-entry` will not be in that list.

Comment: Would it be possible default to the entry of a different locale if one is turned off.